# How to prevent automatic screen lock on android by code?

Tags: android, android-screen, android-screen-support

In my app there is a long loading process, and if the devices puts on the screen lock, my process stops for some reason.

How can i prevent the device from automatic screen lock?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

you have to declare this uses-permission on AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

And in your code Activity:

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Lock");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

Just remember to release this lock when your application is paused or destroyed by  doing this:

```
wakeLock.release();
```

Usually, it's suggested to call the **acquire** method inside the **onResume()** of your activity and the **release** method in **onPause()**. This way we guarantee that our application still performs well in the case of being paused or resumed.

Comment: FULL_WAKE_LOCK has been deprecated since API 17, FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON is now the way to go :)

Comment: [`PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK) may be more appropriate as it prevents the behaviour in the question (_stopping the foreground app_), but nothing else (like _keeping display on_).

Answer (score 47):

Another way to keep the screen lock on without having to request the permission in the manifiest is:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Are you doing your long loading process in the UI thread? Something doesn't seem right - if the process is so long that the screen lock timesout and your process ends, perhaps it needs to go in a background service.

Comment: How can I disable this flag again if I want ?

Comment: Try getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

Answer (score 7):

**XML Way:**

Just use `keepScreenOn` attribute in your parent layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:keepScreenOn="true">
```

**programmatically:**

You can set it programmatically by adding flag:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
lock.disableKeyguard();
```

in androidmanifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
```

**OR**

Follow [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html)

Answer (score 3):

one interesting option that wasn't mentioned yet is the

```
View#setKeepScreenOn(boolean onOff)
```

method. This can actually be used dynamically at any point during the runtime of the app, e.g. for setting the screen mode depending on the app state

Answer (score 3):

The following line allows your phone to be ON when the app is in foreground

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

The following instructions allow us to disable the lock screen when lock button is pressed. KeyguardLock class was deprecated in API level 13

```
/*onCreate*/
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE); // Deprecated :/
lock.disableKeyguard();
```

And in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Go with the key guard code its working perfectly,**

Just Paste the code in onCreate Method in your mainactivity file And 
Permission in android manifest file

Comment: Support for another answer should be disclosed with an upvote, not by creating an answer.