# Bluetooth Connectivity issue in android 5.0(lollipop)

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-5.0-lollipop

I am developing Bluetooth based app.

There is one user who wants to share data to other user’s phone through Bluetooth . 
I am facing one issue.

Device is paired with other device. But if paired device has Android 5.0 (Lollipop) and above version of android OS then I face problem, The problem is when screen is off that time connection will be lost.  Below Android 5.0 it work s properly.  **“In short problem face in Lollipop”**  So why this is happen ?

Here is my code.

```
    private BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
    mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            if (!mAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
                Intent enableBTIntent = new Intent(mAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivity(enableBTIntent);
            }

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver1, filter);
    find = new ArrayList<String>();
    mAdapter.startDiscovery();


final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver1 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
            pdialog = ProgressDialog.show(FindPeopleActivity.this,
                    "Please wait", "Device Scanning...");
            // discovery starts, we can show progress dialog or perform
            // other tasks
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED
                .equals(action)) {
            if (pdialog != null && pdialog.isShowing())
                pdialog.dismiss();
        } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // bluetooth device found
            BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            find.add(device.getAddress());

        }

    }
};
```

In Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

If there is any solution, link, any difference  approach there would be great and helps lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there possible when data is transferring that time paired device must be unlock. (just for Lolipop device only) Can you do some hardcode for screen isnt lock of lolipop device.?

Answer (score 2):

Staring with Android 6.0 it is not enough to include permissions on manifest. You have to ask the user explicitly about each permission that is considered "dangerous"`.BluetoothDevice. ACTION_FOUND` requires `BLUETOOTH and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions`

```
 uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

if this doesn't work then post your error log.

Comment: **<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>,i think its use for GPS..so why i use this in Bluetooth??**

Comment: Background scanning for Bluetooth devices in Android 6.0, including beacons, now requires either android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION. :)

Comment: i add this permission and try..but not working.:-( have some other idea??

Comment: when i scan from my app,lollipop device not found in lower versions phone but perfectly show in default bluetooth from phone settings..I think its version compatible issue in my app??? i used `android:targetSdkVersion="23"`

Answer (score 0):

I have different approch to handle this issue.

Device will be wake up till data,file etc does not transfer. when finished then release this lock in activity onDestroy().

So this is just for android 5.0 or above. You have to first track sdk then find API Level 21 and ablove then implement this apporch.

see this: [Screen Lock and unlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344333/how-to-prevent-automatic-screen-lock-on-android-by-code)

Comment: yes its good idea but firstly device not found from lower to higher version.for  example my lollipop device can't found from jellybean device.

Comment: So can you check, Default bluetooth setting ? is there devices is listed or not ?sometimes connection is lost even already connected. For example , see setting of bluetooth in kitkate device (which is search lolipop device) Is Lolipop device is visible. If visible then is check device is able to pair or not? if not then on-off bluetooth and scan again from ur kitkate device.

Comment: yes i check in default bluetooth setting,device listed perfectly..but in my app device not visible...